# How can I center this HTML/CSS slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm trying to center the JavaScript slideshow and "Slideshow header" that you can see in image left. Below you can see what my website looks like on the left and on the right is how I want to center my slideshow.

[image: Website]

I tried adding `text-align: center;` to my CSS but nothing changes.

### HTML

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <h1 class="text-muted">Slideshow</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="slider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li class="slide slide1">slide1</li>
                <li class="slide slide2">slide2</li>
                <li class="slide slide3">slide3</li>
                <li class="slide slide4">slide4</li>
                <li class="slide slide5">slide5</li>
                <li class="slide slide1">slide1</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
```

### CSS

```
#slider {
    width: 720px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;    }

#slider .slides {
    display: block;
    width: 6000px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;      }

#slider .slide {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 720px;
    height: 400px; }

.slide1 {background:red;} 
.slide2 {background: blue;}
.slide3 {background: green;}    
.slide4{background: purple;}
.slide5 {background: pink;}
```

Comment: Use [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or similar for javascript code, no screenshots!

Comment: Please add the code as actual code, and not as a photo, so we can use this to test things ourselfs

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Amongst other things, post code and markup and such **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Hello I tried to fix the issue. Could I get some assistance please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
#slider{
    width: 720px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;      
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Paco. Additionally, how can I center my slider's header?

Comment: Add width:100%; and text-align:center; to the h1 element. And please mark the solution correct! :) @delealli